# Sum of all subsets of the set of even coprime integers relative to a power of a prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, induction

Let $p$ be an **odd** prime and $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $S$ be the set of even coprime integers relative to $p^k$, i.e.
$$S=\{2,4,\ldots,2\frac{p^k-1}{2}\}\setminus\{2p,\ldots,2p\frac{p^{k-1}-1}{2}\}.$$

For example, for $p=5, k=2$ then $$S=\{2,4,\ldots,24\}\setminus\{10,20\}=\{2,4,6,8,12,14,16,18,22,24\}$$

> **Question**: If we take all the sums of all subsets of $S$ (with at least one element and without repeating elements), can we get all the even numbers up to the sum of all elements of $S$?

I could prove it easily by induction in the case of $k=1$ (in this case $S$ is simply $\{2,4,\ldots,p-1\}$) and I checked it for some low powers for example $9,25,27$. I think that this is true but I don't know how to manage a proof for $k\geq 2$ or find a counterexample. Maybe this is related to the Euler's totient function $\varphi$.

Any comment or sugerence will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of $S$ for some $p^k$? I'm having trouble understanding its construction.

Comment: For example for 9, $S=\{2,4,8\}$, 2+4+8=14. In this case 6=2+4, 10=8+2, 12=4+8.

Comment: @AleTolcachier  Is $p^k$ the upper bound for the elements in $S$ ?

Comment: If you mean the last element in $S$, then yes, the last element is $p^k-1$ so $p^k$ is "the" upper bound